# How to position elements with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

How could it be possible use Flex css to leave the elements as follows?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `margin-left: auto` on second element and that will push second and third element to right.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.content > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content > div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also achieve this with `margin-right: auto` on the first element. In this case the main horizontal align is flex-end and only the first div is flex-start. Because of that you can push the first div with `margin-right: auto` to the left and the others will keep the flex-end alignment. So every additional div will also be positioned to the right side.

```css
#wrapper{
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.box:nth-child(1){
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box:nth-child(2){
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
}

.box:nth-child(3){
  background: rgba(255,0,255,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```